# What is the find and replace "s/{pattern}/{string}" format called?

Tags: find-and-replace, string, standards

`s/{pattern}/{string}` keeps coming up in find and replace contexts (vim, sed).

Is this a standard way of presenting find and replace strings? Does it have a name? Is there a standard somewhere for this kind of stuff?

Comment: It comes from the ed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor) editor. Possibly because of the shared ancestry of sed and vim.

Comment: They're called [regular expressions](http://vimregex.com/) and have been common in programming for decades. Different programs implement them differently; you have to read the documentation, you will not be able to understand them by guessing.

Comment: Here is some history lesson from god https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTfOnGZUZDk

Comment: The guys over on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ might be able to give you more of a history lesson on the origins.

Comment: @spikey_richie That looks like a great community!
@DourHighArch Oh, I thought just the `/{pattern}/` was a regular expression.

Comment: Also, the info on ed is just what I was looking for. Thanks user1937198 and Biswapriyo!